# Can't filter recent codes on ideone

Tags: browser, website, ide

Guys I recently have been unable to filter the recent code section of ideone by any particular language.
Whenever I select filter by C, C++ or Python or any Language, other language codes also appear.
Is this just for me?
http://ideone.com/recent

Comment: It doesn't work for me either (latest Firefox) :/